# How can I convert timestamp to time4j Moment format?

Tags: java, android, time4j

I have a problem with Time4J library, I can not convert specific timeStamp to Moment format.

for example, I want something like this: `Moment.timeInMillies = myTime` or `Moment.of(myTime)`

`myTime` is a `long` value of milliseconds since the epoch, which can be obtained via `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: @OleV.V. no, just time in long format, a value which can be obtained via  System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I think the best conversion is

```
TemporalType.MILLIS_SINCE_UNIX.translate(myTime)
```

`MILLIS_SINCE_UNIX` can translate between `Long` and `Moment`, so the call implicitly boxes your `long`.

**Original answer:** I haven’t got the experience, but the way I read the documentation either of the following should work:

- `Moment.of(myTime / 1000, Math.toIntExact(myTime % 1000 * 1_000_000), TimeScale.POSIX)`
- `Moment.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(myTime))`

I might have missed a more elegant way, though, I don’t know.

**Links**

- [`TemporalType.MILLIS_SINCE_UNIX` documentation](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/TemporalType.html#MILLIS_SINCE_UNIX)
- [`Moment` documentation](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Moment.html)